# Relationship not working and looking for a strange table name?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, many-to-many

I have created a migration for a lookup table with a many to many relationship.

```
   Schema::create('user_partner__organization', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('partner_organization_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');

        $table->foreign('partner_organization_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('partner_organizations');
    });
}
```

Then I am setting up the relationships to be able to go through the user_partner__organization table

In UserPartnerOrganization model

```
public function partnerOrganizations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PartnerOrganization::class);
}
```

And in PartnerOrganization

```
   public function userPartnerOrganizations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserPartnerOrganization::class);
    }
```

And finally I am trying to go through the relationship to get a user_id when I know the partner_organization_id which I have in the $organization

```
    $test = $organization
            ->partnerOrganization()
            ->first()
            ->userPartnerOrganizations()
            ->first();
```

The partnerOrganization relationship is working nicely but when I try to implement the userPartnerOrganizations I get this error in my log file

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.partner_organization_user_partner_organization' doesn't exist in /home/vagrant/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:359
```

Don't understand where this strange table name is coming from or why the relationship is not working.

Answer (score 1):

since your not following Laravel convention in tables name, you have to provide the pivot table name in relation declaration:

```
public function partnerOrganizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PartnerOrganization::class,'user_partner__organization','user_id','partner_organization_id');
}

 public function userPartnerOrganizations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserPartnerOrganization::class,'user_partner__organization','partner_organization_id','user_id');
    }
```

also note that the relation from both side should be `belongsToMany`

more about many to many relation in [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: The partnerOrganizations is defined in a different model connected to a different table 'partner_organizations'. It shouldn't be hasMany because has the primary key that is nested in user_partner__organization? Doing the changes as you said gave me another error:  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_partner__organization.user_partner__organization'

Comment: it should be belongsToMany both side, then other problem could be fixed

Comment: try to provide full arguments to the relation, like the updated answer